# python: groupby list of dataframes in to smaller lists of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, list, pandas-groupby

I have a number of dfs stored in a list (df_list). Some dfs share an identical column ('b'). dfs with this identical column should be extracted from the list and stored into a new list of dataframes. Is there a way to 'groupby' dfs in a list programmatically, to handle more cases where this will happen?

Example data and the expected output is shown below. all comments welcome. thanks so much

**example data**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 2, 3], 'a': [1,2,3], 'b': ['t1','t1','t1']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [10, 11, 12], 'a': [2,3,4], 'b': ['t1','t1','t1']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 2, 3], 'a': [1,2,3], 'b': ['t2','t2','t2']})
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 2, 3], 'a': [1,2,3], 'b': ['t3','t3','t3']})
df5 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [10, 11, 12], 'a': [2,3,4], 'b': ['t1','t1','t1']})

df_list = (df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)
```

**expected output** : grouped lists

```
df_list_t1 = (df1, df2, df5)
df_list_t2 = (df3)
df_list_t3 = (df4)
```

Comment: [k for g,k in pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]).groupby('b')]??

Comment: Are trying to group identical dfs?

Comment: @nk03 thanks so much, that nearly works but it stores the three dfs that include t1 in column b as a single dfs, but i would prefer to have that as a list of three separate dataframes.

Comment: @DanielButler thanks for asking, no they are not actually identical, but the variable in b column will be identical, and that's what i would like to group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group the dataframes:

```py
from itertools import groupby

out = []
for _, g in groupby(
    sorted(df_list, key=lambda k: k["b"].tolist()), lambda k: k["b"].tolist()
):
    out.append(list(g))

# pretty print the list:
for subl in out:
    print(*subl, sep="\n\n")
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
   id  a   b
0   1  1  t1
1   2  2  t1
2   3  3  t1

   id  a   b
0  10  2  t1
1  11  3  t1
2  12  4  t1

   id  a   b
0  10  2  t1
1  11  3  t1
2  12  4  t1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   id  a   b
0   1  1  t2
1   2  2  t2
2   3  3  t2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   id  a   b
0   1  1  t3
1   2  2  t3
2   3  3  t3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: this is perfect thanks. my next step is to run a loop only on lists that contain more than one dataframe. do you think this could be incorporated in to the same command?

Comment: @br101 Yes, if you want to print lists with more than one dataframe, you can do something like: `if len(subl) > 1: ...`

Comment: ah thanks so much yes of course! out of curiosity, i am trying to access dfs stored within the list with e.g. out[1] but i cannot access for instance, the second dataframe stored in the first element of the list (where b = t1) unless i subset it before hand. is there a way around that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply as below using `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dfs = defaultdict(list)

for df in [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]:
    k = df['b'].unique()[0]
    dfs[k].append(df)

df_list_t1, df_list_t2, df_list_t3 = list(dfs.values())
```

**Output:**

```
>>> df_list_t1
[   id  a   b
0   1  1  t1
1   2  2  t1
2   3  3  t1,    
   id  a   b
0  10  2  t1
1  11  3  t1
2  12  4  t1,    
   id  a   b
0  10  2  t1
1  11  3  t1
2  12  4  t1]
>>>
>>> df_list_t2
[   id  a   b
0   1  1  t2
1   2  2  t2
2   3  3  t2]
>>> 
>>> df_list_t3
[   id  a   b
0   1  1  t3
1   2  2  t3
2   3  3  t3]
```